# Actor from an actor use case

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case

I'm unsure on how this relationship would work in a use case. I was hoping somebody would shed some light on this for me by explaining the relationship and the behaviour accessible by each?

[image: Use case example]

Comment: Hi there is something wrong with your drawing here.
Could explain what you wanted to depict? What are the meaning of these relations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This relationship is not allowed in UML 2.0.

> UML 2 does not permit associations between Actors. (1)(2) The use of generalization/specialization relationship between actors is useful in modeling overlapping behaviours between actors and does not violate this constraint since a generalization relation is not a type of association.(3)
>   ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_(UML)))

Although Applicant is a valid concept to the system, (s)he is not a system user; therefore, it should not be an actor in the use case diagram. Even for regular use case descriptions this relationship does not matter. What matters is the user and system interactions. However, you are free to explain this relationship in a [user story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_story).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is legal UML it does not have a well defined semantic. It says: `Applicant` is associated with `Artist Manager` but does not tell what kind of relation that is.

Just think by yourself: what does it tell? If you can't give a meaningful answer then it's probably nonsense.

Judging from the UC I guess that `Applicant` is a secondary actor. You should relate it to the UC like `Artist Manager`. In the past I used an undirected association for the secondary actor. Alternatively you may stereotype it with `<<use>>` or the like. Just be consistent with the notation.

Comment: This is the question relating to the use case. Which do you think would be the answer considering that it's not very well defined.

[Question link](http://i.imgur.com/oV0K1RQ.png)

Comment: Only c) is covered by this diagram. And this wrongly as stated above. Please note: this is not the place to get your homework done!

Comment: This isn't homework, this is a previous exam paper for my university which makes it even more laughable. We haven't covered this method which is why I was confused. Thanks for the help.